The mobx decorator syntax in the tsx file will not load properly in React native applications after babel conversion
.babelrc
{
    "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
          "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
          {
            "legacy": true
          }
        ]
      ]
}

@observer class EditComment
Use the babel above on the tsx file
After @observer is converted, the file cannot be imported.
If you have encountered similar problems, please help me, thank you！
